# Save content of selected Excel cell to .txt on button click

Tags: vba, excel

I have a broadcasting software that can read .txt files and display the content (just a few words) inside a lower third graphic whenever the .txt is updated.

I would like to show different texts throughout the broadcast (like titles of a segment) in the following way:

- I would prepare a list with every possible lower third text in an Excel column.
- Then I select a cell and on the click of a button, Excel would save/overwrite the .txt with the content of the selected cell only - this triggers the broadcasting software to show that text.
- Then I select the next cell, click the button, Excel overwrites the file, the broadcasting software shows that text.

How would I do this in Excel/vba?

I don't want to write the lower thirds during the broadcast, because I am already busy enough with hosting the stream. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I found a good start here: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/13012-saving-selection-text-file.html Is it possible to not ask for a range but take the already existing selection and also not ask for a file location but put a DynamicText.txt right next to the Excel file?

Comment: Did you not see the solution below?

Comment: Oh yeah haven't seen it yet! Thanks I am going to try it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reference to the file system object `FSO`, then use the `CreateTextFile` method. The `True` statement overwrites the existing file.

> You will need to change the file path I provided to something useful. I used that fake path for illustration purposes.

Also, if you do not want the msgbox prompt asking if you are sure you want to broadcast, simply delete those two lines.

Try this:

```
Sub writeTxt()

    Const txtFilePath$ = "C:\Folders\txtFile.txt"

    Dim rng As Range, FSO As Object
    Set rng = ActiveCell

    If MsgBox("You sure you want to broadcast:" & vbNewLine & _
            rng.Text, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Sub

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    With FSO.CreateTextFile(txtFilePath, True)
        .WriteLine rng.Text
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a "permission denied" error. Is there a security setting I have to change somewhere first?

Comment: Is the text file already open? If you already have full write permissions then I don't think that would be the issue. You can't overwrite the text file if it's open by another application AFAIK.

Comment: Now it suddenly works... must have been an open file issue. Anyway... wow it works! This will make my next broadcast so much more awesome! I appreciate your help so very much! :D